# Laravel: Eager loading duplication

Tags: laravel-4

I'm trying to set up eager loading to prevent N+1 queries, but I'm finding that I have to duplicate some eager loads in order to get laravel to use the 'eager loaded' data.  Duplicating the eager loads of course results in duplicated queries.

This is my load call:

```
$provider->load('ads.gallery.images', 'ads.thumbnail', 'ads.user', 'ads.provider.values.field', 'values.field', 'galleries.images');
```

A provider is a polymorphic subtype of a user.  This is for a user profile page, which displays the user `values` list, as well as a list of all their ads.  The ad display is a sub-view that's reused across the site and has a tab that displays the user `values` list as well.  Yes it's redundant on this page, but that's how the site is designed.

I would expect laravel to reuse the already-loaded `values.field` list when the sub-view accesses it, but it doesn't, so I had to add `ads.provider.values.field` to the list, which duplicated the queries:

```
select `provider_field_values`.*, `provider_values`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `provider_values`.`value_id` as `pivot_value_id` from `provider_field_values` inner join `provider_values` on `provider_field_values`.`id` = `provider_values`.`value_id` where `provider_values`.`user_id` in ('3')
select * from `provider_fields` where `provider_fields`.`id` in ('1', '2', '3')
select `provider_field_values`.*, `provider_values`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `provider_values`.`value_id` as `pivot_value_id` from `provider_field_values` inner join `provider_values` on `provider_field_values`.`id` = `provider_values`.`value_id` where `provider_values`.`user_id` in ('3')
select * from `provider_fields` where `provider_fields`.`id` in ('1', '2', '3')
```

Is there any way I can eliminate this duplication?  I'm not sure if the issue is in how the views access the data or if it's in the controller.  I can add snippets of the view code if needed.

Edit: Model relationships:

```
//Provider model
public function values()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('ProviderFieldValue', 'provider_values', 'user_id', 'value_id');
}

//ProviderField model
public function fieldValues()
{
    return $this->hasMany('ProviderFieldValue', 'field_id');
}

//ProviderFieldvalue model
public function field()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('ProviderField');
}

//ProviderValue model (this is a pivot table)
public function provider()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Provider');
}

public function fieldValue()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('ProviderFieldValue');
}
```

Comment: Do you have your Models relationships properly setup?

Comment: @HelderLucas which Models?  I can add them to the post so you can verify them

Comment: The ones that are involved in your query

Comment: `ads.provider.values.field` you should think about denormalization. Your relations are quite deep in levels.